# Force registration from specific email domain

Tags: google-app-engine, email, jinja2

I'm using google app engine and jinja to create a signup form that asks users to signup with their email address. However, I'd like emails to only come from a specific domain (e.g. gmail.com).

How do I send an email to the entered address to ask for confirmation?

I'm not sure how to hook up Python with PHP/Ruby to write the email confirmation script.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form you can send mails with the Python Mail API like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
....
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender = YOUR_GAE_EMAIL_ADDRESS, subject = 'confirmation request')
message.to = 'john.doe@gmail.com'
message.body = 'Confirm your email address using ...'
message.send()
```